# Aggregating based on GROUPING of multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle, count, distinct, common-table-expression

I am trying to subquery and aggregate in SQL after doing an initial query with multiple joins. My ultimate goal is to get a count (or a sum) of specimens tested based on a grouping of multiple columns. This is slightly different from [SQL Server query - Selecting COUNT(*) with DISTINCT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521605/sql-server-query-selecting-count-with-distinct/1521656#1521656) and [SQL Server: aggregate error on grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51482446/sql-server-aggregate-error-on-grouping).

The three tables that I use (PERSON, SPECIMEN, TEST), have 1-many relationships. So PERSON has many SPECIMENS and those SPECIMENS have many TESTS. I did three inner joins to combine these tables plus an additional table (ANALYSIS).

```
WITH TALLY as (
SELECT PERSON.NAME, PERSON.PHASE, TEST.DATE_STARTED, TEST.ANALYSIS, SPECIMEN.GROUP, TEST.STATUS,
 ANALYSIS.ANALYSIS_TYPE, SPECIMEN.SPECIMEN_NUMBER
    FROM DB.TEST
    INNER JOIN
    DB.SAMPLE ON
    TEST.SPECIMEN_NUMBER = SPECIMEN.SPECIMEN_NUMBER
    INNER JOIN 
    DB.PRODUCT ON
    SPECIMEN.PERSON = PERSON.NAME
    INNER JOIN
    DB.ANALYSIS ON
    TEST.ANALYSIS = ANALYSIS.NAME
    WHERE PERSON.NAME = 'Joe'
    AND TEST.DATE_STARTED >= '20-DEC-16' AND TEST.DATE_STARTED <='01-APR-18'
    AND PERSON.PHASE = 'PHASE1'
    ORDER BY TEST.DATE_STARTED)
    
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ANALYSIS) as SPECIMEN_COUNT, DATE_STARTED, ANALYSIS, STATUS, GROUP, ANALYSIS_TYPE
    FROM TALLY 
    GROUP BY DATE_STARTED, ANALYSIS, STATUS, GROUP, ANALYSIS_TYPE
    ORDER BY DATE_STARTED;
```

This gives me the repeated columns: first grouping repeated 4 times

[image: first grouping repeated 4 times]

What I am trying to see is: aggregated first grouping with total count

[image: aggregated first grouping with total count]

Any thoughts as to what is missing? SUM instead of COUNT or in addition to COUNT creates an error. Thanks in advance!

9/17/2020 Update: I have tried adding a subquery because I also need to use a new column of metadata (ANALYSIS_TYPE_ALIAS) which is created in the first query through a CASE STATEMENT(...). I have also tried using another subquery with inner join to count based on those conditions to a temp table, but still cannot seem to aggregate to flatten the table. Here is my current attempt:

```
WITH TALLY as (
SELECT PERSON.NAME, PERSON.PHASE, TEST.DATE_STARTED, TEST.ANALYSIS, SPECIMEN.GROUP, TEST.STATUS,
 ANALYSIS.ANALYSIS_TYPE...
    FROM DB.TEST
    INNER JOIN
    DB.SAMPLE ON
    TEST.SPECIMEN_NUMBER = SPECIMEN.SPECIMEN_NUMBER
    INNER JOIN 
    DB.PRODUCT ON
    SPECIMEN.PERSON = PERSON.NAME
    INNER JOIN
    DB.ANALYSIS ON
    TEST.ANALYSIS = ANALYSIS.NAME
    WHERE PERSON.NAME = 'Joe'
    AND TEST.DATE_STARTED >= '20-DEC-16' AND TEST.DATE_STARTED <='01-APR-18'
    AND PERSON.PHASE = 'PHASE1'
    ORDER BY TEST.DATE_STARTED),
SUMMARY_COMBO AS (SELECT DISTINCT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(ANALYSIS, DATE_STARTED),STATUS), GROUP), ANALYSIS_TYPE_ALIAS))AS UUID,
TALLY.NAME, TALLY.PHASE, TALLY.DATE_STARTED, TALLY.ANALYSIS, TALLY.GROUP, TALLY.STATUS, TALLY.ANALYSIS_TYPE_ALIAS
FROM TALLY)
SELECT SUMMARY_COMBO.NAME, SUMMARY_COMBO.PHASE, SUMMARY_COMBO.DATE_STARTED, SUMMARY_COMBO.ANALYSIS,SUMMARY_COMBO.GROUP, SUMMARY_COMBO.STATUS, SUMMARY_COMBO.ANALYSIS_TYPE_ALIAS,
COUNT(SUMMARY_COMBO.ANALYSIS) OVER (PARTITION BY SUMMARY_COMBO.UUID) AS SPECIMEN_COUNT
FROM SUMMARY_COMBO 
ORDER BY SUMMARY_COMBO.DATE_STARTED;
```

This gave me the following table [Shows aggregated counts, but doesn't aggregate based on unique UUID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJmIh.png). Is there a way to take the sum of the count? I've tried to do this by storing count to a subquery and then referencing that count variable, but I am missing something in how to group the 8 columns of data that I want to show + the count of that combination of columns.

Thanks!

Comment: can you share in db fiddle. I guess the issue is with `COUNT(DISTINCT ANALYSIS)`  change it to `COUNT(ANALYSIS)`

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `analysis` from the `group by` clause, since that's the column whose distinct values you want to `count`. Otherwise, the query generates more groups than what you need (and the count of distinct `analysis` values in each group is always `1`).

```
WITH TALLY as ( ...)
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ANALYSIS) as SPECIMEN_COUNT, DATE_STARTED, ANALYSIS, STATUS, GROUP, ANALYSIS_TYPE
FROM TALLY 
GROUP BY DATE_STARTED, STATUS, GROUP, ANALYSIS_TYPE
ORDER BY DATE_STARTED;
```

Comment: Thanks @GMB, I did try this, however I am still not getting the count of 4 that I would expect. Instead I have get 98 as the count for the first group (with the rows still repeating). Is it possible that my joins are causing repeated values and I need to use distinct in the first query?